# scipy leastsq fit - penalize certain solutions

Tags: python, scipy, constraints, least-squares

I have implemented an algorithm that is able to fit multiple data sets at the same time. It is based on this solution: [multi fit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23574555/4141279)

The target function is too complex to show here (LaFortune scatter model), so I will use the target function from the solution for explanation:

```
def lor_func(x,c,par):
    a,b,d=par
    return a/((x-c)**2+b**2)
```

How can I punish the fitting algorithm if it chooses a parameter set `par` that results in `lor_func < 0`.

A negative value for the target function is valid from a mathematical point of view. So the parameter set `par` resulting in this negative target function might be the solution with the least error. But I want to exlude such solutions as they are nor physically valid.

A function like:

```
def lor_func(x,c,par):
    a,b,d=par
    value = a/((x-c)**2+b**
    return max(0, value)
```

does not work as the fit returns wrong data as it optimizes the 0-values too. The result will then be different from the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `bounds` argument of [scipy.optimize.least_squares](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html)?

```
res = least_squares(func, x_guess, args=(Gd, K),
                    bounds=([0.0, -100, 0, 0],
                            [1.0, 0.0, 10, 1]),
                             max_nfev=100000, verbose=1)
```

like I did here:
[Suggestions for fitting noisy exponentials with scipy curve_fit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42407051/suggestions-for-fitting-noisy-exponentials-with-scipy-curve-fit/42500533#42500533)

Comment: Bounds are not an option as I do not know them beforehand. It is a problem of the targe function which has a term `power(a, b)`. Sometimes `a<0` which does then result in `nan` if `b` is a broken number. This I have solved by returning a negative number when 'nan' occurs. So I have to prevent him from finding solutions where the target function becomes negative.

Comment: It seems that this approach is the only working one. It requires some fiddling with the bound but works.